# Hi to everyone ; I tested all these REgex above ; but none of them returned any result

Tags: regex

I tested all these REgex above ; and they returned good results. 
But I would like to find and replace not a line BUT a chain. That means that two same chains of characters can follow in the same line. And I would like to find and replace the second one.

Any help ? What should I change in the Regex

```
^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)
```

I' m working with Notepad+.

Thanks a lot to all of you who can help me not spending my life sorting lines and chains!
Steph

Comment: I only see 1 regex and it is not "above" anything. We also don't know what you are testing against. Please update the question.

Comment: What are your regexes, what is your input? And what is your expected output? Voting to close as I do not know what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex you can use to match repeating sequences of 2 or more characters. The first group captures the first occurrence and the second all the rest:

```
([\s\S]{2,})(\1+)
```

You may modify the `2` in the regex to specify the minimum number of chars that should be considered a sequence.